# When i click on NavBar button it appears, but it is not disappear when i click on it again

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "rgba(0,0,0,0.6)";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
}

$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    if ( $(e.target).closest('#sideNavButton').length ) {
        $("#mySidenav").show();
    }else if ( ! $(e.target).closest('#mySidenav').length ) {
        $('#mySidenav').hide(); document.body.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    }
});
```

```css
.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 20px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
        <a href="#" class="active">HOME</a>
        <a href="#">MEN</a>
        <a href="#">WOMEN</a>
        <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
        <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
      </div>
```

The side navbar can open on click the button, once the side navbar is open it can be close by anywhere click on the page, but not close by clicking on the open button, i want that it also close on clicking the open button & anywhere on the screen also. my complete HTML, CSS ,jquery and javascript code is here. What i do?

Answer (score 0):

Please Try This:

HTML:-

```
<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="openbtn">Open</a>
  <div id="mySidenav">
     <a href="#" class="active">HOME</a>
     <a href="#">MEN</a>
     <a href="#">WOMEN</a>
     <a href="#">ABOUT</a>
     <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:-

```
#mySidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0px;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;   
    padding-top: 60px;
    transition: width 250ms;
    -webkit-transition: width 250ms;
}

#mySidenav.show{
    width: 250px;   
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 20px 8px 8px 32px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 25px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
.openbtn{
    z-index: 3;
    position:relative;
}
```

JS:-

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
$('.openbtn').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
    if($(this).hasClass('active')){
        $(this).html('Close');
        $('#mySidenav').addClass('show');   
    }else{
        $(this).html('Open');
        $('#mySidenav').removeClass('show');
    }
});


$(document).on('click', function(e) {

var $trigger = $(".sidenav");       
if($trigger !== event.target && !$trigger.has(event.target).length){
    $('.openbtn').removeClass('active').html('Open');
    $('#mySidenav').removeClass('show');
}
});
});
```

Comment: It is not working, even by using this the side navbar cannot open by clicking on button.

Comment: can you share link of your mockup?